# ReactiveCocoa replayLast: + take:1

Tags: ios, objective-c, functional-programming, reactive-cocoa

I came across a code snippet in ReactiveCocoa 2 that uses the combination of replayLast and take:1.  Given that replayLast returns one element only, is take:1 redundant?

```
[[[[ ... ] replayLast] take:1] switchToLatest];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not redundant: `replayLast` will start replaying the last element, **but it will continue emitting any subsequent values** after the initial one.